# Can I define an animation for a moving element when DOM is changed?

Tags: html, css, css-transitions, css-animations

```
<div>
    <div id="foo"></div>
    <div id="bar"></div>
</div>
```

When the height of `#foo` changes, the position of `#bar` changes too. Can I animate it?
  There seems to be no `position` property to be used on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_animated_properties).